# Can matplotlib errorbars have a linestyle set?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, errorbar

Is it possible to set the same linestyle on matplotlib errorbars as the data points?

In the example below, two lines are plotted. One of them is dashed because of the `ls='-.'` parameter. However, the errorbars are solid lines. Is it possible to modify the style/look of the errorbars to match the results line?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.array(range(0,10))
y = np.array(range(0,10))
yerr = np.array(range(1,11)) / 5.0
yerr2 = np.array(range(1,11)) / 4.0

y2 = np.array(range(0,10)) * 1.2

plt.errorbar(x, y, yerr=yerr, lw=8, errorevery=2, ls='-.')
plt.errorbar(x, y2, yerr=yerr2, lw=8, errorevery=3)
plt.show()
```

Comment: It looks like an open issue (feature request) in matplotlib: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/2366

Comment: Looks like this functionality is currently not available. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It is trivial, changing the linestyle of the errorbars only require a simple `.set_linestyle` call:

```
eb1=plt.errorbar(x, y, yerr=yerr, lw=2, errorevery=2, ls='-.')
eb1[-1][0].set_linestyle('--') #eb1[-1][0] is the LineCollection objects of the errorbar lines
eb2=plt.errorbar(x, y2, yerr=yerr2, lw=2, errorevery=3)
eb2[-1][0].set_linestyle('-.')
```

[image]

Comment: Any idea if the `dashes` option can be specified?

Comment: @oliversm Yes, you can use words or symbols as specifiers. `'dashed'` equals `'--'`.

Comment: @smcs not `dashed` but `dashes`, such as `ls='-', dashes=(10, 5)`...

Comment: @oliversm Sorry :D I just fiddled some and yes you can do that like so: `eb1[-1][0].set_linestyle((offset,onoffseq))`, where e.g. `offset = 2` (specifies where the dashing starts) and `onoffseq = (10,5)` (specifies pattern just like using the `dashes` option for other plots).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the **fmt** option that is included in the `plt.errorbar()` command.

For example, in your case:

```py
plt.errorbar(x, y, yerr=yerr, fmt='-.' , lw=8, errorevery=2)
plt.errorbar(x, y2, yerr=yerr2, lw=8, errorevery=3)
```

Comment: This changes the format of the lines joining the points, not the lines which constitute the error bars