# Matplotlib - Dashed error bars on a bar plot

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, bar-chart

I'm trying to modify the errorbars on a bar plot so that they are dashed instead of the default solid black. I've tried to use the linestyle = '--' kwarg on plt.bar() but did not see a change in output.

I have also tried the solution recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22995797/can-matplotlib-errorbars-have-a-linestyle-set) using

`name=plt.errorbar(x, y, yerr=yerr)
name[-1][0].set_linestyle('--')`

But this doesn't give a dashed error bar on my bar plot either. Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Copy-pasting the provided code as is, gives dashed error bars for me (Windows 10, PyCharm Community Edition, Python 3.7, Matplotlib 3.1.1). So, can't reproduce.

Comment: The provided code also works properly for me, and I get dashed error lines (python 2.7, matplotlib 2.2.2)